# Python List of Lists Incrementing

Tags: python, list

```
x  = 0

y = []

for i in range (5):
    y.append(x)
    x+=1

print y
```

Gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But,

```
x  = range (2)

y = []

for i in range (5):
    y.append(x)
    x[0]+=1

print y
```

I would have thought (hoped) that this gives me:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
```

But instead it just gives me:

```
[[5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1], [5, 1]]
```

I've tested it by putting 'print y' inside the for loop, and obviously what is happening is that when x[0]+=1, all the 'x's that are already inside 'y' are being updated with the new value.

How do I write the program so that it 'forgets' that the 'x's already in list 'y' are still variables (and so doesn't keep updating them)?

I've realized I could just write this one specifically as:

```
y = []

for i in range (5):
    x = [i, 1]
    y.append(x)
```

But what if I wanted to define x outside of the for loop? I can't think of a time when I would want to do it this way but I just want to know anyway.

Comment: *"How do I write the program so that it 'forgets' that the 'x's already in list 'y' are still variables"* - this makes no sense. Pyton doesn't really have "variables", it has names that are references to objects (see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). You fill `y` with *multiple references to the same list*. To fix it, copy; `y.append(x[:])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@tzaman gives the perfect solution, but you want your own code:

```
x  = range (2)

y = []

for i in range (5):
    y.append(x[:]) #You should append copy of x
    x[0]+=1

print y
```

gives:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1]]
```

Comment: or  just append(range(2))

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one. tzaman's solution was alright but not really what I was asking, so this one's better.

Answer (score 2):

If you define `x` outside the for loop, it's a reference to the same list every time. If you want each sub-list to be independent you have to create it inside the loop. Your final code-block works.

However, a more concise and pythonic way of doing what you want is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
y = [[i, 1] for i in range(5)]
```